# How to declare constants in kotlin similar to Java

Tags: android, kotlin

- In Java class, I usually declare all my constants in a single
  constant file and access across the project
- How to achieve the same in kotlin

---

**Java Code:**

```
public class LinksAndKeys {
    public static String BASE_URL = "http://11.111.111.11:8000/";
    public static double TAXABLE_AMOUNT = 0.18;
    public static int DAYS_INTERVAL_FOR_RATE_ME_DIALOG = 50000;
}
```

### *What is Equivalent Kotlin code ? *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin, we do not necessarily need to put constants in a class, so these are valid in a Kotlin source file:

```
const val BASE_URL = "http://11.111.111.11:8000/"
const val TAXABLE_AMOUNT = 0.18
const val DAYS_INTERVAL_FOR_RATE_ME_DIALOG = 50000
```

If you want to keep the `LinksAndKeys` namespace, you could use:

```
object LinksAndKeys {
  const val BASE_URL = "http://11.111.111.11:8000/"
  const val TAXABLE_AMOUNT = 0.18
  const val DAYS_INTERVAL_FOR_RATE_ME_DIALOG = 50000  
}
```

You can then refer to values like `LinksAndKeys.BASE_URL`, either from Java or Kotlin.